# How to authenticate with express-oauth-server?

Tags: node.js

I want to implement an oAuth2 Server using nodejs for my app, and I'm using tutorial found on https://niceprogrammer.com/express-js-oauth-2-server-using-oauth2-server-package/

However, when I go to https://localhost:3000/oauth/authenticate (login route) and try to login, i get a json response: `` {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing parameter: `client_id`"} ``

The function responsible for authenticating is as follows:

```
router.post('/oauth/authenticate', async (req, res, next) => {

    let UserModel = mongoose.model('User');
    req.body.user = await UserModel.findOne({ username: req.body.username });

    return next();
}, oauth.authorize({
    authenticateHandler: {
        handle: req => {
            return req.body.user;
        }
    }
}));
```

Is there an issue with the tutorial or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it, I was missing the `?client_id=xxx` in the url.